# Write a systemd unit service to start an application with different arguments after an unclean exit

Tags: linux, systemd, raspbian, services

I need a systemd unit service to start an application without arguments and restart it with arguments should it crash.

I have several applications written and they work. But you never know and therefore I would like them to restart in verbose mode should they ever crash, so I have more information's within the log-files.

I am running this on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian / Linux 9 (strech) and Systemd 232-25+deb9u2.

```
[Unit]
Description=Example Application
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/exampleApp
ExecRestart=/home/pi/exampleApp -V
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

I got the service starting and restarting the application. Starting with dependencies to other services works, too. But I can't find a solution to start with arguments on a restart of the application.

Any ideas how to start the application with arguments after a crash / unclean exit?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an easy solution (so perhaps starting the apps by default in verbose mode might be worth considering).

Here is a suggestion that does at least part of what you want. The service unit shown below starts the app in normal mode (the `ExecStart=`) if the app behaves well. If the app fails to start for some reason, the service runs a second try (the `ExecStopPost=`) in verbose mode.

```
[Unit]
Description=verbose-start-on-failure Service
After=app.service

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/pi/exampleApp
ExecStopPost=/home/pi/exampleApp -V

[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

However, if the app is started successfully but for some reason crashes later in time this service unit will not automatically restart it (adding a `PartOf=` dependency won't work).